# Custom WordPress Options Function

Tags: php, wordpress, function

What is in my functions:

```
$var = get_option('to_twitter_feed');

array( "name" => "Twitter Username",
    "desc" => "Enter your Twitter username for the Twitter feed",
    "id" => $shortname."_twitter_feed",
    "type" => "text",
    "std" => ""),
```

In my WordPress options I have a custom twitter widget.  I want users to be able to simply type their name in the input and have it inserted into the widget code.  Most of this code is complete: **basically, I just need to know how to put the what is called in first code below into the second code.**

How I call it:

```
<?php echo get_option('to_twitter_feed'); ?>
```

The code I need to put it into (where it says THEUSERNAME):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(function($){
        $(".tweet").tweet({
            username: "THEUSERNAME",
            join_text: "auto",
            avatar_size: 32,
            count: 3,
            auto_join_text_default: "said,", 
            auto_join_text_ed: "we",
            auto_join_text_ing: "we were",
            auto_join_text_reply: "replied to",
            auto_join_text_url: "was checking out",
            loading_text: "loading tweets..."
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what is the output when you write print_r($var); ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you get twitter username by

```
<?php echo get_option('to_twitter_feed'); ?>
```

then

you can set twitter username in java script like this

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(function($){
        $(".tweet").tweet({
            username: "<?php echo get_option('to_twitter_feed'); ?>",
            join_text: "auto",
            avatar_size: 32,
            count: 3,
            auto_join_text_default: "said,", 
            auto_join_text_ed: "we",
            auto_join_text_ing: "we were",
            auto_join_text_reply: "replied to",
            auto_join_text_url: "was checking out",
            loading_text: "loading tweets..."
        });
    });
</script>
```